# Java android exception when reading sourcecode

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to read the source code from the craigslist location page.  Sometimes I get an exception and don't understand why.  It's weird through my phones 3g it will work for a while then out of no where it starts throwing the exception.  When I test it on my WiFi it throws this exception 75% of the time.

---

```
07-08 02:43:39.542: W/System.err(16898): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
07-08 02:43:39.562: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
07-08 02:43:39.562: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
07-08 02:43:39.566: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
07-08 02:43:39.570: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
07-08 02:43:39.570: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
07-08 02:43:39.574: W/System.err(16898):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
07-08 02:43:39.574: W/System.err(16898):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:255)
07-08 02:43:39.574: W/System.err(16898):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:128)
07-08 02:43:39.578: W/System.err(16898):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
07-08 02:43:39.578: W/System.err(16898):    at com.codalata.craigslistchecker.GetLocation.GetLocationData(GetLocation.java:56)
07-08 02:43:39.578: W/System.err(16898):    at com.codalata.craigslistchecker.Location$1.run(Location.java:407)
07-08 02:43:39.582: W/System.err(16898):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

---

I'm just trying to read from the server.  Any help would be appreciated!

I put the counter in the while loop to see how many times it loops before the error.  Sometimes it loops 519 times and others it loops like 400 times.

```
public class GetLocation {
int CityindexEnd;
int CityindexStart;
int StateC;
String URLME = null;
String Search = "a href=\"";
int count = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public String GetLocationData()
        throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites");
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 6000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 12000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            sb.append(l + ln);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
                    return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                return URLME;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return URLME;
    }
}
```

Comment: apparently there is nothing returned by the server for a long time or your internet connection is slow, did you try the request by running it on web browser?

Comment: I load it on my browser just fine.  If you change the url to something like http://www.yahoo.com/ it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to change timeout?

Comment: Yes if I timeout it gives me those errors.  If I take the timeout away nothing happens.  It just continues to try to get data from the server forever.

Comment: maybe there is no eof returned from server?

Comment: If I am on 3g it gets the source code very quick with no errors

Comment: As others say, handle the exception! BTW, since you are accessing the site 400 times in a row, perhaps some sort of DoS detector is dropping you into a honey pot?

Comment: I am trying to think of how to get an exception. Let me take a lot of junk out of the code

Comment: I thought the was the best way to read some source code.  Am I really trying to access the server like 400 times in a row?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a timeout with

```
int timeoutConnection = 4000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
        timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 7000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```

Basically, you're losing connectivity (or never fully have it) and are taking too long.  If you don't want to timeout, you can remove these lines.  If you do, you need to handle that excecption gracefully.

Comment: Web browser is fine loading the page.  Also if I sub in http://houston.craigslist.org/ for the url it reads it fine.  I set the timeout up to tell it to just give otherwise it just sits there doing nothing.  My internet is very fast.

Comment: The web browser has a much longer timeout, if any at all.  You're setting 4 and 7 seconds, those are pretty damn small.  At any case, if you specify a timeout you have to handle the possibility or you can randomly crash.

Comment: The timeout was removed so now it just keeps trying to read from the page.  If I change the url it reads good.

Comment: Sounds like something server side.  Continuing to try without those timeouts is the behavior I'd expect.

Comment: I was thinking the same I can change my url to anything else and it works just fine but it acts up if I use that url.